# Angular multiple directives with shared data model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The main point of this post is that I want to avoid using $scope.$watch as it is taught to cause a performance decrease.

So imagine having one shared view partial/template, call it "mypage" with two different directives, call them "directive1" and "directive2", in it that share a data model, lets call it "awesomeData"

Maybe it looks something like this:

```
<div class="mypage-root">
   <directive1 shared-data="awesomeData"></directive1>
   <directive2 shared-data="awesomeData"></directive2>
</div>
```

Now obviously when "awesomeData" changes in either directive or the root view, the data changes in the other parts too (assuming it is two-way bound).

But what if i want something else to happen in directive2 when directive1 has updated the data model, like calling a function in directive2?

I could use a watcher but as mentioned, that is a performance decrease.

What other approaches are there and what is the "true" angular way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you're asking about how to do this without a watcher, but I think in this instance a watcher is the best answer as it gives separation of concerns. `directive1` shouldn't have to know about `directive2`, but only about `MySharedService` and anything it might broadcast:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('myVar.updated');
```

...

```
$scope.$on('myVar.updated', function (event, args) {
});
```

**Edit:**

Also, depending on the complexity of the model the directives will be using, you could pass this model from their parent controller (The down side to this is that you have to instantiate a model from a parent):

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <directive1 my-model="model"></directive1>
    <directive2 my-model="model"></directive2>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = { info: 'Starting...' };
});

app.directive('directive1', function() {
  var controllerFn = function($scope) {
    $scope.changeInfo = function() {
      $scope.vm.myModel.info = 'Directive 1';
    };
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: controllerFn,
    template: '<div><span>hello</span> <span ng-bind="vm.myModel.info"></span> <button ng-click="changeInfo()">Click</button></div>',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    scope: {
      myModel: '='
    }
  }
});

app.directive('directive2', function() {
  var controllerFn = function($scope) {
    $scope.changeInfo = function() {
      $scope.vm.myModel.info = 'Directive 2';
    };
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: controllerFn,
    template: '<div<span>bye</span> <span ng-bind="vm.myModel.info"></span> <button ng-click="changeInfo()">Click</button></div>',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    scope: {
       myModel: '='
    }
  }
});
```

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/EwdHFl7eZl2rd43UVG4J?p=preview

**Edit 2:**

As with method 2, you could have a shared service, that provides this `model`:

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/EwdHFl7eZl2rd43UVG4J?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using the approach of instantiating the model in the parent controller, however I'm still not sure whether it is possible to invoke a function in directive2 when directive1 changes the model. As it is I need to update some directive2 specific data based on changes to the (common) data in directive1. EDIT: without using a watcher that is.

Comment: Ah yes....If you have some directive specific logic that needs to be processed when there is a data change, then I really think a watcher is the best way to go, even if it *seems* a bit dirty

Comment: @mda144 I've just added an Edit 2. Perhaps that would be a better solution for you? It does get round the watchers, and allows each directive to make changes to the data. I'm not sure of your exact use-case however, so don't know if that is a better solution.

Comment: For now the watcher solution will work as it is a relatively small application I'm making with maybe just one or two watchers, but for larger projects, perhaps I should reconsider my strategy. Thank you for your answers and suggestions.